# Getting average of Parsed string

Tags: c#

I am currently working on scrum poker project and I set up server to write client's inputs.

It is currently working but when I parsed string which they wrote I have a list of inputs.

I need to find average of it but i can't, please show me some directions !

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\poker\vote.txt"))
    {
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        string[] items = line.Split('\t');
        int myInteger = int.Parse(items[0]);

        string path = null;
        foreach (string item in items)
            {
            if (item.StartsWith("item\\") && item.EndsWith(".ddj"))
                path = item;
                }
            }
        }
```

// this is mine vote.txt for those who asked

```
  TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //getting data with networkstream
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            //reading the stream
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"c:\poker\vote.txt"))
            {
                w.WriteLine(dataReceived);  //datareceived contains
                                            // numbers 1 to 100 in 
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
            }
```

Comment: So you need to sum up all the `myInteger` values and divide by the count?

Comment: Well the average is the sum of items divided by the number of items, so write some code to do that.

Comment: You  are using Tab Delimited so my question is there any columns that are empty of have extra tabs?

Comment: Can you add a part of what contains VOTE.TXT file in your question so that we have an idea of what is parsed ?

Comment: Save them in an array and after the 'while' is completed you can calculate the average

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa , i tought about that but  i couldnt add them to array somehow

Comment: @DavidG yes you could say that

Comment: No, that was me telling you what to do!

Comment: Post the contents of vote.txt, not the function that generates it

Comment: @schlebe thx for answer , i added

Comment: Please, can you put the content of vote.txt file (only 1 line is enough) and not the source code that generate it ! It is important to have a Q&A that are well documented and that can be used by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `while` define an empty list to store your values:

```
var votesList = new List<int>();
```

Inside the `while`, whenever you parse a value, add it to your list:

```
votesList.Add(myInteger);
```

Finally, when you finished parsing the file, get the average:

```
var avg = votesList.Average();
```

Don't forget the `using`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @MertcanBayraktar Good to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Try finding average as below.

```
int average = Convert.ToInt32(items.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Average());
```

Comment: thanks for your question but it only gives outputs , not average